# redefine ampersand & for environment

Tags: macros, catcodes

I want to redefine the ampersand-charakter to expand to a macro, I defined. Basically it is/should be something like

```
&={\hspace*{30pt}Ampersand has been redefined\hfill}
```

The final use is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{encap}[1]{ { % make definitions of \ns local / limit scope
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ns}{s O{0 pt}}{%
    \ifx\tempi\undefined%
        \newlength{\tempi}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\tempi}{##2}%
    \divide\tempi by 2%
    \ifx##1\BooleanTrue \hskip 0pt plus 1fill minus 1fill \hspace*{\tempi}-\hspace*{\tempi}%
        \hskip 0pt plus 1fill minus 1fill%
    \else% 
        \hskip 0pt plus 2fill minus 2fill \hspace*{##2}%
    \fi%
}%\ns

%Pseudocode:
&=\ns

\makebox[\textwidth]{#1}
}} % encap

\begin{document}
\encap{this\ns equals& this}
\ns % out of scope
& % should be restored
\end{document}
```

BTW.: The `\ns` command works exactly as intended

Comment: Why don't you make a complete example? And did you really thought throught the consequences if you make & is active and it no longer can be used in a tabular?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought this through (at least I think). Inside of `\encap` there can't be used the tabular-environment, but this is absolutely okay.

Comment: So you want that `&` does `\ns` only inside the argument to `\encap`?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz if you change the catcode of `&` inside `\encap` then `\encap` will acquire the same restrictions as `\verb` and can not be used inside the argument of any other command, is that OK?

Comment: `\newcommand{encap}[1]{ { % make definitions of \ns local / limit scope` that line means that every use of `\encap` inserts two word spaces into the document, is that what you need?

Comment: @egreg exactly this way.

Comment: you should never do this `\ifx\tempi\undefined%
        \newlength{\tempi}%`  the `\new` allocation is global but the name goes out of scope so you will be allocating a new register every time. (classic tex only had 256 of them, etex has more but still....) the \newlength should always be at the top level not in a macro used multiple times.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately no, it must be used in another command (actually environment). But this isn't too bad at all. The idea was only to make the use of `\encap` more convenient. To type `\ns` instead of `&` can be exhausting. It is used quite often inside `\encap`.

Comment: You could use `expl3` and do a `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \ns }`.

Comment: I can't tell from that comment whether not allowing \encap in an argument is OK or not. If you want to make & active it needs to be globally active or restrict encap, although I suspect you don't really need to define `&` at all just define \encap` to take two arguments separated by `&` and put the processing i   \encap, which is much more robust.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It should actually go out of scope, but I thought it would be dumped. So this would be okay. So I should assign `\newlenght` global and assure by proper nameing that it doesn't interfere with other packages.

Comment: @Manuel Will it break, if I use `\encap` in other commands. I suppose, that expl3 changes the catcodes here. Which would mean as David stated, that it would break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\ns` is used inside `\encap` and should not be visible outside. `\encap` itself is used in a custom environment (NewEnviron). The content of the environment (the `\BODY`) is packaged into another command, which will be called from the document.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz It won't break.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz egreg has given you a start but \ns looks wrong to me what is the intended behaviour of \hspace* following a hskip?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It shifts the next word. Normally the space is devided equally. If there is anywhere to less space, it can be enlarged manually. The general purpose of this is to attach lyrics to notes which are included as pdf. Concerning the `\newlength`: I just dump it. I introduced it just for readability of the code.

Comment: No I mean the only purpose of `\hspace*` rather than `\hspace` is to avoid the space being dropped at the start of a line, but if you were at the start of a line the first `\hskip` would have been dropped

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are probably right. I did it just to be sure it doesn't disappear anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what is the intended usage of `\ns`; however, here's an implementation.

I fixed the most obvious weaknesses in your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\tempi}

% define active & to be normal &
\begingroup\lccode`~=`&
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}&
% make & active
\catcode`&=\active

\newcommand{\encap}[1]{\begingroup\let&\ns#1\endgroup}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ns}{s O{0 pt}}{%
  \unskip
  \setlength{\tempi}{\dimexpr#2/2}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {%
     \hspace{0pt plus 1fill minus 1fill}%
     \hspace*{\tempi}-\hspace*{\tempi}%
     \hspace{0pt plus 1fill minus 1fill}%
    }
    {%
     \hspace{0pt plus 2fill minus 2fill}\hspace*{#2}%
    }%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\encap{this \ns equals & this}}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\encap{this \ns* equals &* this}}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\encap{this \ns*[10pt] equals &*[10pt] this}}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 text & text \\
 a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's ecactly what it should do.